# Friend functions with templates

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend

I have a generic class , Array1d, with a friend function declared as,

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std ::ostream& out, Array1D<T>& a);
```

and defined as

```
template<typename U>
std::ostream& operator<< (std ::ostream& out, Array1D<U> a){
    for(int i=0;i<a.size;i++){
        out<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    out<<endl;
    return out;
}
```

but if I try,

```
Array1D<int> a;
cout<<a;
```

I get this error

```
(1).cpp|62|error: template-id 'operator<< <>' for 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Array1D<int>&)' does not match any template declaration|
```

I have tried instatiating it explicitly for int,

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std ::ostream& out, Array1D<int> a){
    for(int i=0;i<a.size;i++){
        out<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    out<<endl;
    return out;
}
```

But it gives the same error. Help appreciated.

Comment: A minimal, working example to be used to reproduce the error would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std ::ostream& out, Array1D<T>& a);`
2. `template<typename U>
   std::ostream& operator<< (std ::ostream& out, Array1D<U> a)`

These two are not the same functions. This is because `Array1D<T>` is a concrete type. If you want 1. to match for 2., you need to make it a template, possibly by making it `Array1D<U>`. You might as well check that T=U, if you want to be over-cautious.

Comment: Is there a way to do this, without defining the function inside the class?

Comment: Yes, the template<U> is still defined outside the class.